# Get the values which is inside nested object

Tags: php, json, object

```
{"networks":{
  0 : {
     "ssid":"asdf",
     "rssi":"test",
     },
  1 : {
     "ssid":jkl",
     "rssi":"fubar",
    }
}}
```

I need to get ssid(which is inside 0 and 1) value in foreach loop. can any one help me to solve this problem. thanku

Comment: Apart from the invalid json, which may just be a typo, I would suggest you look up [`json_decode()` in the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the JSON string using [json_decode()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) before you can use it in PHP

```
$json_parsed = json_decode($your_json_string);
foreach ($json_parsed['networks'] as $network) {
    $network_ssid = $network['ssid'];
    // do whatever you want with the network SSID
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

As RiggsFolly pointed pointed out, you have get JSON objects as associative arrays. The syntax is: `json_decode($json_string, true)`

Comment: Note: They are objects defined in that JSON String! And you are addressing them as if they were arrays!!